# Angular ui-router nested views - the page isn't loading when direct url is used

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to access a nested view with the direct url, without navigating through links but it's not working.

My config is:

```
myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('st1', {
            url: '/st1',
            templateUrl: 'st1.html',
        })
        .state('st1.st2', {
            url: '/st2',
            templateUrl: 'st2.html',
        })
    ;
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

st1.html:

```
<h1>ST1</h1>

<div ui-view></div>

<a ui-sref="st1.st2">ST2</a>
```

st2.html:

```
<h2>ST2</h2>

<a ui-sref="st1">ST1</a>
```

I go directly to /st1, typing it not clicking a link, st1 html shows up.

When I click the link in st1, the location path changes to /st1/st2 and st2's content shows up, that is what I want, but when I refresh on /st1/st2 the page is empty.

What do I miss?

Comment: That would be almost for sure your server configuration. Carefully check the FAQ https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: The index.html is loading but the views' aren't.

Comment: It's working with hashbang so yea my server conf must be the problem, but it seems to be good:
`root 'application#index'`
`get '*path' => 'application#index'`

Comment: This issue is for sure about the server setting. Check carefully the FAQ I gave you. If server is set properly, all will start to work. Here is [working example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26009350/1679310)

Comment: Gosh.. it was my fault. I always forget not to learn new things before the 3rd coffee... thanks for the help, it works now.

Comment: Great to see that sir, UI-Router is awesome lib... ;)

Comment: Indeed. It should be angular's official router. :)