# How to configure controllers for stateprovider with TypeScript

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router

Let's assume I have following simplified controller:

```
module App {
    "use strict";

    export class StoreDetailController {
        constructor() {
            alert("Detail-Controller");
        }
    }
}
```

The `UI-Router` is configured as follows (simplified):

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ui.router"])
    .config(($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) => {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
        $stateProvider.state("store", {
            url: "/Store",
            templateUrl: "/Store/Partial?name=Layout"
        });
        $stateProvider.state("store.Detail", {
            url: "/Details/:id",
            templateUrl: "/Store/Partial?name=Details",
            controller: StoreDetailController
        });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

Everything is working fine (the message box appears) when I enter the details page from the start page of the app. But if I am reloading the browser on the details page or paste the nested url into a new tab, the controller is not been called and no error is raised.

Everything seems to work too if I 'declare' the controller directly at the configuration, like:

```
//...
$stateProvider.state("store.Detail", {
    url: "/Details/:id",
    templateUrl: "/Store/Partial?name=Details",
    controller: () => alert("This is called every time");
});
//...
```

What is the correct way to configure the state provider that the controller is used on reload or entering nested urls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the most suspected, and mostly the culprit, would be inproper HTML setting.

Simply a browser needs to know, what is the **base** `href` for all relative navigation. And that could be confusing for it *(for the browser)* if we navigate directly to `https://domain/app/Store/Partial?name=Layout`. To solve it we just need to set the element `<base>`

```
<base href="/" />
```

Check this [Q & A about html5mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26009350/1679310), with working example/plunker

Interestingly there is also other way for Angular's $htmlProvider, and it is it configuration:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
   enable: true,
   requireBase: false.
});
```

Check the doc:

#### [$locationProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider)

*small cite about configuration:*

> - **enabled** – {boolean} – (default: false) If true, will rely on history.pushState to change urls where supported. Will fall back to hash-prefixed paths in browsers that do not support pushState.
> - **requireBase** - {boolean} - (default: true) When html5Mode is enabled, specifies whether or not a tag is required to be present. If enabled and requireBase are true, and a base tag is not present, an error will be thrown when $location is injected. See the $location guide for more information
> - **rewriteLinks** - {boolean} - (default: true) When html5Mode is enabled, enables/disables url rewriting for relative links.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried to set the `<base>` element (within the `<head>` element of the page) but it is still no working. Anyway, by setting the `requireBase` option to `true` the controller is called now on reload. The only thing is that a `#` sign is added now to the url. For now it is ok (playing around with angular and typescript), but hopefully I will find a solution for this in the near future.