# Angular-UI-Router stops working when a namespace is declared before id parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, javascript, angular-ui-router-extras

I am making a simple blog section in my website so i want to have a namespace called posts, that dynamically links to a post template. These posts will each have their own template( i.e. posts/some_post.html ) as they are too different to just use json data to populate a generic template.

I want to have a namespace that allows me to create links to each post so that in production I can post: mysite/posts/my_new_post. However, prepending the posts in the .state url leads to a failure to instantiate module error.

This is a snippet of the working code:

```
.config(["$urlRouterProvider", "$stateProvider","$locationProvider", function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider,$locationProvider){

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$stateProvider

  .state('posts', {
    url: '/:postID',
    templateUrl : function($stateParams){
      return 'templates/posts/' + $stateParams.postID + '.html';
    },
  });


}]);
```

This code works and i can link to the URIs that get generated. When this link is clicked:

```
li><a ui-sref="posts({postID: 'blog2'})">blog 2</a></li>
```

The URI become website/blog2, and from website/home, i can link to the URI

HOWEVER, if I try to add a namespace I get a failure:

```
.state('posts', {
    url: '/posts/:postID',  // note i added posts before the id
    templateUrl : function($stateParams){
      return 'templates/posts/' + $stateParams.postID + '.html';
 },
```

The link will work the first time, and take me to the correct page however,
if i type the URI pattern mysite/posts/blog1 i get the: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] error, and this weird:Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Somehow it isn't loading angular, anyone have nay ideas?

Comment: You need some form of [URL rewriting for HTML5 mode](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#server-side) to handle the initial page. Do you have that? Also, what's the full error and location?

Answer (score 0):

You are using html5mode, which requires two things to be configured properly:

- server part - server simply must know, that some requests are not for the server.. they are virtual. Some redirect must happen. Check how to here: [How to: Configure your server to work with html5Mode](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode)
- client part - browser must be able to understand which part of url should be treated as relative.

To answer the second part, check [this Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28359363/1679310) or [that Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26009350/1679310) for an **woring** example/plunker.

*Short story:*

In general, we have to provide HTML element **`<base>`** with a default value of the **href**

```
<base href="/" />
```

*Longer story:*

What it does? Well, as you've experienced - if we directly navigate to site: `https://domain/index.html` - browser does understand that relative part is "/".

But if we change routing to `/state/:ID` - resulting url is `https://domain/state/abc` - which is fine if we navigate there from already laoded `index.html`.

In case we navigate directly to `domain/state/abc` - the **base href** could be very different then we need. And that's where the `<base href="` should help.

Also, the doc could help:

#### [$locationProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider)

We can for example ask for html5mode like this:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
   enable: true,
   requireBase: false.
});
```

see more details [also here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28359363/1679310)